# JDBC Prepared Statement Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into a vehicle table using a prepared statement. [This is the table shown in PHPMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AstzG.jpg).

This is my java code

```
 try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO vehicle (vin, serial, make, model, year, reg.no., status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, vin);
        statement.setString(2, serial);
        statement.setString(3, make);
        statement.setString(4, model);
        statement.setInt(5, 10);
        statement.setInt(6, 17);
        statement.setString(7, status);
        System.out.println(statement.toString());

        int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (rowsInserted > 0) {
            System.out.println("A new user was inserted successfully!");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

and this is the resulting error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' status) VALUES ('dfg', 'dfgfg', 'fg', 'sd564', 10, 17, 'dsf')' at line 1
```

I am clueless. Does it have to do with me not passing a value for the primary key "id" column in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reg.no.` isn't a valid column name. If you really need to use it, you should quote it:

```
INSERT INTO vehicle (vin, serial, make, model, year, `reg.no.`, status) 
-- Here ---------------------------------------------^-------^
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```